# How to load different html depending on screen width?

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I want to change the `siteType` value depending on screen width without editing in view part.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('Location', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/', { templateUrl: 'pages/' + **params.siteType** + '/locationList.html', controller: Location }).
        when('/locationDetail/:projectId', {
          templateUrl: function (params) { return 'pages/' + **params.siteType** + '/locationDetail.html'; },
          controller: Location
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }])

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
    $location.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

**Controller.js**

```
'use strict';
function Location($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.projectId = $routeParams.projectId;
    $scope.selectedProject = null;
    $scope.locationList = null;
    $scope.siteType = "desktop";

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if(window.innerWidth < 600) {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
              $scope.siteType = "mobile";
            });
        } else {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
              $scope.siteType = "desktop";
            });
        }
    });

    $http.get("location.json")
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.locationList  = data;
        var indexedloc = [];
        $scope.locationListToFilter = function(){
            indexedloc = [];
            return $scope.locationList;
        }

        $scope.filterLocation = function(Loc){
            var locationIsNew = indexedloc.indexOf(Loc.field_data_field_location_field_location) == -1;
            if(locationIsNew){
                indexedloc.push(Loc.field_data_field_location_field_location);
            }
            return locationIsNew;
        }

        $scope.returnFilterLoc = function(){return indexedloc};
        if($scope.projectId && $scope.projectId != null) {
            for(var i = 0;i < $scope.locationList.length;i++){
                if($scope.locationList[i].tid == $scope.projectId) {
                    $scope.selectedProject = $scope.locationList[i];
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        $("div.category-wrapper").html("Error");
    });
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: You should consider looking into http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a directive or controller that sets the value of what is included:

e.g.

```
 <div  ng-controller="MyController">
    <div  ng-include="{{ template }}"></div>
  </div>
```

and on your controller you can set the value of template depending on the window or document

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

e.g.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   if($(window).width() < 1199)
      $scope.template = "mytemplate1.html"
   else
      $scope.template = "mytemplate2.html"
}]);
```

But all the above is a messy, not safe, ugly solution. You should handle the responsiveness using CSS media-queries.

Comment: I cant use media-queries, because I want to avoid unwanted codes from DOM

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you mean by unwanted codes but you can use `display: none` to hide something on a specific screen-width using media queries.

Comment: Yes I mean the same thing (display:none).
Do you have any solution for changing the variable "siteType" which I mentioned in above?

Thank you for your help.